# How to set Eloquent model attribute values with bindings?

Tags: laravel, pdo, eloquent

Here's an example of the need:

```php
$user->realestate = DB::raw('ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(?)', [$geometry]);
$user->save();
```

Of course, you can put anything like `unaccent`, `unhex`, `to_tsvector` instead of `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`. There's plenty of cases where you need to set a non-trivial expression.

Unfourtunately, the bindings aren't supported here. Is there any proper/sane solution for this? What I've seen is

- not using bindings and inserting the value directly in expression
- ditching eloquent and using query builder or just `DB::execute`
- overriding eloquent core functions that save the model
- using `addBinding`, sometimes with a hack to fix order

None of these solutions seem really "right" and much more like a clumsy and risky workaround.

Comment: No it's not possible to do this. Even the `addBinding` functions are not going to work because this is modifying the model instance and then calling save which will save the literal values you've put there. Some success can be found if you do `User::where('id', $id)->addBinding($geometry, 'update')->update([ 'realestate' => DB::raw('ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(?)')]);` but as you said this is a bit hacky